# A question about cardinal arithmetics without the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Is multiplication of infinite cardinals defined in ZF without Choice?

Comment: This may sound silly, but what exactly do you mean by multiplication? Multiplication of (real/natural) numbers? Multiplication of cardinals?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant multiplication of infinite cardinals.

Answer (score 18):

I assume that you mean multiplication of cardinals.

Finite multiplication is *always* defined, since it is just Cartesian product which is defined regardless to the axiom of choice.

So if $A$ and $B$ are sets the set $A\times B$ exists, and $|A|\cdot |B|=|A\times B|$. This is indeed the definition.

Furthermore, if $B=\varnothing$, then $A\times B=\varnothing$, why? Note that $\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B$ if and only if $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. In the case where one of the sets is empty the product is empty. This means that regardles to the axiom of choice $|A|\cdot 0 = 0$.

What the axiom of choice *does* tell us that we can define *infinite* products, that is $I$ is some infinite index set, if for all $i\in I$ we have that $X_i\neq\varnothing$ then the axiom of choice assures that $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is not empty.

Without the axiom of choice there are such families whose product is empty, and other families of sets whose product is non-empty. However we always have to require that $X_i\neq\varnothing$ for all $i\in I$ since otherwise the result is simply $\varnothing$.

It is also worth noting that without the axiom of choice $\aleph_\alpha\cdot\aleph_\beta = \aleph_{\max\{\alpha,\beta\}} = \max\{\aleph_\alpha,\aleph_\beta\}$. When assuming the axiom of choice every infinite set has the cardinality of $\aleph_\alpha$, so $|A|\cdot|B|=\max\{|A|,|B|\}$. Without the axiom of choice there are cardinals which are not well-ordered and are not equal to any $\aleph$. In particular there are cardinals which are incomparable, so $\max\{\frak p,q\}$ becomes undefined.

**Added:** (after the comment)

Assuming the axiom of choice, if $\lambda_i$ is an infinite cardinal, the $\prod\lambda_i =|I|\cdot\sup\{\lambda_i\mid i\in I\}$. This means that if $X_i$ is a set whose cardinality is $\lambda_i$ we have:

$$\left|\prod X_i\right| = \prod|X_i| = \prod\lambda_i = |I|\cdot\sup\{\lambda_i\mid i\in I\}$$

Without the axiom of choice this equality does not hold *for every family*. Therefore it is not well defined. We can have a model in which there is a countable family of pairs without a choice function. So we have the following situation:

$$0=|\varnothing|=\left|\prod_{n\in\omega} P_n\right|\neq\prod_{n\in\omega} |P_n| = \left|\prod_{n\in\omega}\{2n,2n+1\}\right| = 2^{\aleph_0}$$

Showing that an *infinite* product of cardinals is not well-defined, since cardinality is an equivalence relation and operation on cardinals should not be dependent on choice of representatives. In fact, in certain situation *there is no possible choice of representatives*. So all in all we cannot say that the operation of infinite products (or sums) is well-defined without the axiom of choice.

---

**Further reading on this site:**

1. [There's non-Aleph transfinite cardinals without the axiom of choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53752/theres-non-aleph-transfinite-cardinals-without-the-axiom-of-choice/53753#53753)
2. [About a paper of Zermelo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/54904#54904)
3. [For every infinite $S$, $|S|=|S\times S|$ implies the Axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56466/for-every-infinite-s-s-s-times-s-implies-the-axiom-of-choice/56471#56471)
4. [Defining cardinality in the absence of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53770/defining-cardinality-in-the-absence-of-choice/53771#53771)
5. Somewhat similar question: [Multiplying Infinite Cardinals (by Zero Specifically)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100820/multiplying-infinite-cardinals-by-zero-specifically/100833#100833)
6. Also the comments here: [The Axiom of Choice and the Cartesian Product.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101004/the-axiom-of-choice-and-the-cartesian-product/101008#101008)

Comment: So, without choice it is possible that A*0=C where C is nonzero?

Comment: No. It is possible that there is an *infinite family of sets* and $\prod X_i=\varnothing$, so the cardinality $|\prod X_i|\neq\prod|X_i|$.

Comment: Which cardinals would be "incomparable"?

Comment: @user23648: If $A$ is a set that cannot be well ordered, we can have $\alpha$ the minimal ordinal for which there is no injection into $A$ (remember that finite subsets of $A$ can be well ordered, and possible *some* infinite subsets). It appears in several of the links I've added to my answer that this $\alpha$ is a cardinal (i.e. an ordinal which has no bijection with previous ordinals) and $|A|$ is incomparable with $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for these excellent answers. I've read them, but I've also bookmarked them so I can study this at a later date after I've learned more. This has been a valuable resource. I now realize that there is much more to this subject than I had anticipated.

Comment: @user23648: Tell me about it... :-) If you have further questions, I will be glad to answer.

Comment: @Asaf: I have concerns about your statement that an infinite product is *undefined*. The argument in your answer simply shows that you can't compute the product as $|I| \sup \lambda_i$, not that the cardinal $|\prod X_i|$ depends on how you choose the $X_i$ to represent the $\lambda_i$'s.

Comment: @Hurkyl: First, there might not be a supremum for $\lambda_i$. In fact it is perfectly possible that we cannot even *choose representatives* to calculate such supremum (which obviously depends on the choice of representatives)! Secondly, the cardinality of the product of the sets is indeed defined, but not as a product of cardinalities. Cardinals are equivalence classes, and the product of them is defined on the equivalence classes. If the operation depends on the choice of representatives (and if we sometimes cannot even choose those) then it is simply undefined as a whole.

Comment: @Asaf: Hi Asaf. Do you happen to know if the identity $ |\omega_{1} \times \mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}| $ requires the Axiom of Choice or some weaker version thereof?

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore: Yes. It requires some choice. It is consistent (e.g. in Solovay's model, but also in other models without needing large cardinals) that $|\omega_1\times\Bbb R|>|\omega_1\cup\Bbb R|>|\Bbb R|$.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks! I thought that I could prove this without $ \mathsf{AC} $ by applying the Schröder-Bernstein Theorem (which doesn’t require $ \mathsf{AC} $) to the obvious injection from $ \mathbb{R} $ into $ \omega_{1} \times \mathbb{R} $ and some injection from $ \omega_{1} \times \mathbb{R} $ into $ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $ (which we know to be in bijection with $ \mathbb{R} $ even in the absence of $ \mathsf{AC} $). However, I guess that the problem with this approach is that injecting $ \omega_{1} $ into $ \mathbb{R} $ requires some form of $ \mathsf{AC} $.

Comment: @Berrick: Yeah, that would be the part where choice is used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Multiplication of finite (natural, real, complex, etc.) numbers or of ordinals does not depend on choice.

Cardinal multiplication can be given its usual definition $|A|\times|B|=|A\times B|$, assuming that you have a suitable definition of what a cardinal *is* -- the usual definition of cardinals as distinguished ordinals doesn't work without choice. But rules such as $|A|\times|B|=\max(|A|,|B|)$ for infinite $A$ and $B$ may fail to hold without choice.

Comment: I was concerned about the infinite cardinals. It says on Wikipedia that the result |A|*|B|=Max{A,B} assumes choice. (See the entry on Cardinal Numbers under Cardinal Multiplication)